# Pointers structures and dynamic memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have two structures in which the second structure has the first structure nested inside of it:

```
struct first
{
    int a;
};

struct second
{
    first nested;
};
```

Now the problem is that the second structure has to be dynamically allocated through a pointer.  Also, the nested first structure has to be a dynamically allocated array through a pointer, whose array size has to be read in through an input file.

I know how to read it in but I don't know how to access it. For example lets suppose the size is 8.  How would I go about specifying the values for the second structure given the pointer's format?

I tried assuming `ptr` points to first structure and `ptr1` points to second structure `ptr1->((ptr+count)->a)` where we can process it through a loop. This doesn't work. So I was wondering how you would initialize the values the second structure whose member includes all the n structures in the n element array.

Comment: it sounds to me like you want a linked list... Would you like me to explain linked list to you?

Comment: `nested` isn't an array or a pointer, it's only one element. Are you asking what to change it to? I recommend `std::vector<first> nested;`. Avoid manual dynamic allocations.

Comment: I need to make an array of structure first which is nested inside the second structure. I know they are easier ways to do it but I need to know how to do it this way.

Comment: @VarunGorantla Your question seems to be about very basic issues in [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), and doesn't show enough code to identify a clear problem.  You tagged this question C++, but if you're just getting started then maybe studying a simple [linked list implementation in C](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) would be instructive.  C++ provides facilities for managing many different common data structures, and depending on what you're trying to accomplish you may be able to just take those for granted.

Comment: I understand linked lists might make this eaiser but this task requires dynamic arrays. The essential problem is as stated above inability to access the nested structure. I need a way to access the nested structure members.

Comment: @VarunGorantla Your question, as written, is not clear enough (for me) to understand what your problem is.  You need to add more code and go *"look, here!  this is where I am stuck!"*  The odds are very good that the standard C++ library already has a solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @VarunGorantla well I mean you only have so many options with C++. You can use vector or linked list which both are essentially dynamic arrays that do what you have described.

Comment: The problem is that there's no way for me to access the members for example the same problem when done without dynamic array is straight forward

Comment: @VarunGorantla A `std::vector` is a "dynamic array".  It has contiguous memory allocation; you can get a pointer to the beginning of the data.  It is pre-allocated to a certain size (which you may also control) and if it expands, it is reallocated and copied to the new address.  In C you may implement the same thing, but it is more low level.  However, you did tag this **c++**; if you have invisible constraints coming from an assignment, we have no way of being psychic about what those constraints are.

Comment: Like if it wasn't dynamic arrays then we can simple declare the nested structure as first nested[size] where size can be any integer constant. and then from there we can access each one using second sample.nested[index].a= value

Comment: @VarunGorantla I think I now understand what you think you mean. Here is the problem. Your idea of how structs work is not right. when you create first and set first myFirst; first.a = something; second mySecond;  cout << mySecond.nested.a << endl; will not be anything because they are not connected in anyway. If that is not what you mean then better explain your self.

Comment: I know you have to initialize it first together so it should be

Comment: mySecond.nested.a=value

Comment: You need to clearly state in your question that the solution must use a dynamic array allocated with `new[]`

Comment: I thought that was the only way to dynamically allocate it sorry I'm new to c++

Comment: @VarunGorantla Check my post Answer is that more what you are looking for? Don't forget to pick the best answer btw.

Comment: No it is not I want it the structure to be nested inside the other structure with the nested structure being a dynamic array and the non nested structure being the one with the pointer In the post you are not nesting the structure. Thanks for your time

Comment: `struct second { first *nested; } a; a.nested = new first[2];`

Comment: I don'r understand what you typed can you please walk me through it thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry but you need to get a good book or tutorial on C++ and finish it as this is basic syntax.

Comment: i get the syntax... I just don't get how it answers the question I asked Also why are you doing a.nested that isn't even valid.

Comment: @VarunGorantla You need to use the EDIT button on your question to truly elaborate your assignment.  And if it turns out that your assignment is very "localized" (in a way that you're asking a question that only your teacher/professor would care about, but would not help the rest of the internet) then perhaps you should be having the discussion with them instead of us.  I can't understand you, or what your question/assignment is.  I do not think this is my failure; I think you have failed to make it clear.

Comment: What do you mean it isn't valid? http://ideone.com/LQNVby

Comment: why are the structures being declared inside the main function in my book it always declares it before and why are you making nested 2 nested can be an array of any size

Answer (score 1):

Vector is really easy just stick your struct where type is and use it like any other array. Although what you described really sounds like linked list but hey vector will probably be better for you :)

```
#include <vector>

//main
vector <Type> myArray(8); //set the number of elements you want

myArray[0] = blablabla
```

More specific example:

```
struct first
{
    int a;
};

vector <first> myArray(8);

first[0].a = 1; // you get the idea :)
```

**EDIT**
From the comments this seems to me more up your alley.

```
struct bla { 
 int num;
};

//in main
bla *balBla = NULL;
blaBla = new(bla[8]); //There made on the fly dynamic man
blaBla[0].num = 7; 
//Don't forget to delete when done or scary memory leak!!!
delete[] blaBla;
```

**Last Edit** If this is not what you want then no one will ever understand what you mean

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct b {
    int num;
};

struct a {
    b *nested = NULL;

    a(){} //Default Constructor 

    a(int elements) { 
        nested = new(b[elements]); 
    } //Lets you add elements to nested at initialization

    void addElem(int elements) { 
        if (nested != NULL) {
            delete[] nested;
        }
        nested = new(b[elements]);
    } //Redefine or make new array

    ~a() { 
        delete[] nested; 
    } //destructor
};


int main() {
    a myStupidObj(3);
    myStupidObj.nested[0].num = 69;
    myStupidObj.nested[1].num = 77;
    myStupidObj.nested[2].num = 666;

    cout << "Struct of one D array of structs" << endl;
    cout << myStupidObj.nested[0].num << endl;
    cout << myStupidObj.nested[1].num << endl;
    cout << myStupidObj.nested[2].num << endl;

    //Make 2d version
    a *my2DStupidObj = new(a[2]); 
    my2DStupidObj[0].addElem(3);
    my2DStupidObj[0].nested[0].num = 666;
    my2DStupidObj[0].nested[1].num = 6969;
    my2DStupidObj[0].nested[2].num = 80085;

    cout << "array of struct of one D array of structs" << endl;
    cout << my2DStupidObj[0].nested[0].num << endl;
    cout << my2DStupidObj[0].nested[1].num << endl;
    cout << my2DStupidObj[0].nested[2].num << endl;

    my2DStupidObj[1].addElem(3);
    my2DStupidObj[1].nested[0].num = 11;
    my2DStupidObj[1].nested[1].num = 111;
    my2DStupidObj[1].nested[2].num = 1111;

    cout << my2DStupidObj[1].nested[0].num << endl;
    cout << my2DStupidObj[1].nested[1].num << endl;
    cout << my2DStupidObj[1].nested[2].num << endl;

    delete [] my2DStupidObj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to use dynamic arrays not linked lists not vectors

Comment: It's not necessary to set the pointer to null before calling new.

Comment: @Neil Kirk Hum.. really. I normally set pointers to NULL if they are not pointing to anything. But you are right you could do just set it bla *balBla = new(bla[8]). But I think its better practice to set it to NULL if you are not calling new when you create the pointer - personal preference and all.

Comment: @VarunGorantla, `std::vector` is a wrapper around a dynamic array.  A vector holds a pointer to a dynamic array, and provides functions for accessing its contents.  Most importantly, it has a destructor that automatically frees the dynamic array when the vector is destroyed.  You should prefer to use `std::vector` instead of "raw" dynamic arrays (allocated manually with `new`), unless you have a very good reason not to (such as an assigned requirement, or compatibility with an existing API that you can't change).

Comment: @T.Malo, it makes sense to initialize a pointer to null if it's going to stay that way for awhile and you want to make it clear that the pointer doesn't point to anything yet.  But it doesn't make sense to initialize a pointer to null if you're just going to immediately assign it a value from `new` on the very next line.  Just initialize it with the `new` expression.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you sometimes see something like:

```
struct second {
   int count;
   first nested[1];
};
```

Then, you allocate memory.  The amount you allocate is computed as sizeof(struct second) plus the size of first times the number of elements you want in the array minus 1 (since there is already one included).

```
ptr = (struct second *)malloc(sizeof(struct second) + ((n-1) * sizeof(first)));
```

Then you can use

ptr->nested[idx].a

or if you have to use pointers,

```
((ptr->nested)+idx)->a
```

Of course, you have to do all the housework and cleanup yourself.  C++ and its std libraries do most of that for you.